# Uncompress Gzip data using Amazon Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, gzip, amazon-sqs, gzipinputstream, gzipoutputstream

We have a service which store the compressed data in the data store(SQL table). This data is compressed using java util library **GZIPOutputStream**.

My question is is there a way to uncompress this data using SQL?

Sample compressed data:

"H4sIAAAAAAAAAO2QX2vCMBTFv0ueW9FNXeeb2jgCmoqtDBEpsb2FwExckgpO+t0XYytOGIw9S55y7p/fOXd9QjkzbCjyUGblDoTRC/gsuYJ8IhUWhhsOGg3WJ3SQ2v2PIRjGP6x4o5HcjvKCgzrLUGtogNjuS7SY3Le2peYCtG6xfg+Czkvhb4Og53fhteMH/XbmP2fd/lMWQJcVbeTVO5LjHuyWUT181WNZquxcicIYVZX3a4op18bZZ8Yovi0NXJUDKOs4Y4ZLMWyqlO0ccBkTiuM4nZIxpmOc0uVshBeWr4BpKexxasKZZgdmJLYTbymhkwhVG2vo3oljNupUWq50x2qkuZKyaPI2+PkiiiaWar1qa7MuU/x+vcTNph9C3YppQpJVSkJUeff0usUx0mQ1x+loGGPX+aeU3iPPI88jz7/zbC7vGxsilliEBQAA"

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Amazon redshift.

Comment: no, you need to get the data, and then use: [compression and decompression of string data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351668/compression-and-decompression-of-string-data-in-java)  (* no, because there is also no native method to gzip the data you entered...)

Comment: or, maybe, [MySQL UDF sys_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460809/mysql-udf-sys-exec)

Comment: Why do you need this? It feels like a faulty design to me...